# JavaFX: Disable image smoothing on Canvas object

Tags: image-processing, canvas, javafx, zooming

I'm making a sprite editor using JavaFX for use on desktops.

I'm attempting to implement zooming functionality, but I've run into a problem: I can't figure out how to **disable image smoothing on a `Canvas` object**.

I'm calling `Canvas.setScaleX()` and `Canvas.setScaleY()` as per every tutorial implementing `Canvas` zooming. But my **image appears blurred when zoomed in**.

I have some test code [here](http://pastie.org/private/69zmvyki0wcw8ffztjcwfw) to demonstrate.

[image: What I get][image: What I want]

As this is a sprite editor, it's important for me to have crisp edges to work with. The alternative to fixing image smoothing on the `Canvas` is to have a [non-smoothing `ImageView`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089304/javafx-imageview-without-any-smoothing), and have a hidden `Canvas` to draw on, which I would rather avoid.

Help is appreciated.

---

[(here's a link to a related question, but doesn't address my particular problem)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16209512/is-there-any-javafx-image-editor)

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue with the blurring.

In my case, my computer has Retina Display. Retina Display causes a pixel to be rendered with sub-pixels. When drawing images to the canvas, the image would be drawn with antialiasing for the sub-pixels. I have not found a way to prevent this antialiasing from occurring (although it is possible with other canvas technologies such as [HTML5's Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615009/disable-interpolation-when-scaling-a-canvas))

In the meantime, I have a work-around (albeit I'm concerned about performance):

```
public class ImageRenderer {
   public void render(GraphicsContext context, Image image, int sx, int sy, int sw, int sh, int tx, int ty) {
      PixelReader reader = image.getPixelReader();
      PixelWriter writer = context.getPixelWriter();
      for (int x = 0; x < sw; x++) {
         for (int y = 0; y < sh; y++) {
            Color color = reader.getColor(sx + x, sy + y);
            if (color.isOpaque()) {
              writer.setColor(tx + x, ty + y, color);
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The PixelWriter bypasses the anti-aliasing that occurs when drawing the image.