# Can I add additional info to chart's snapshot in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, charts, snapshot, controlsfx

In my code

```
WritableImage image = chart.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);
```

goes and prints the chart result on the screen. I need to add additional info, like a comment which will have the time in a corner for example.

Is there a way to achieve this other than `chart.setTitle`?

Comment: Does it has to be after you take the snapshot? I mean you could add all the additional using nodes (ex: Label, Text etc.) using an AnchorPane or any layout and then take the snapshot.

Comment: Otherwise have a look in this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16209512/is-there-any-javafx-image-editor

Comment: @JKostikiadis well, the first thing makes more sense, how can I do that?

Comment: @JKostikiadis to a chart ofc.

Comment: I will assume you already know how to create the chart, now you only need is to place it inside an `AnchorPane` (or even a `StackPane`) and then add all the other labels using controls `Label`. After that take the same snapshot but instead of calling  `chart.snapshot...`  you will call `layout.snapshot..`. Try it out if you have problems post an MCVE and i will try to help you in details.