# ImageView Zoomed Blurs Edge Pixels

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I've been scouring the internet trying to find a way to fix my problem. I am creating a top-down rpg style game in JavaFX and have run into a bit of a snag. I'm trying to create a game area of 544 x 416 (area the you can see) but this is obviously pretty small so I've scaled the StackPane to 2.0. The game area is still 544 x 416 it's just larger on the screen.

The way my program is built, I have a StackPane called root that is attached to the Scene (and the Scene is attached to the Stage set at fullscreen), then I have another StackPane called frame attached to root. The StackPane size of  frame is 544 x 416 and the StackPane root is scaled on the x and y axis 2.0 (which obviously scales frame). The StackPane frame is in the middle of the screen.

[image]

The issue comes when I actually try to load a map image. The edge pixels of each ImageView are blurred ever so lightly which creates a thin line whenever two images are placed on top of each other.

[image]

This image is not scaled at all and is exactly the way it should look.

[image]

This final image has been blurred by the scale factor and has a thin black line visible where the two images are. You can also see that the image has been blurred quite a bit. I am very good with Photoshop and know inherently that some pixel blurring will occur when making images larger BUT this issue did not occur with Swing.

I need to know if there is a better way to do this entirely OR how to get rid of the blurring. There is another topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089304/javafx-imageview-without-any-smoothing/16092631#16092631) with a problem somewhat similar but it doesn't really address my particular problem. Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason that prevents you from using images that are twice the size, sou do not have to scale it?

Comment: Yeah that's kind of a tough question. The game was originally designed for a program called RPG maker which has a 640x480 resolution and the gameplay area is 544 x 416. A lot of the graphics are already finished and designed for 32 bit graphics (meaning the game map is broke up into 32 x 32 pixel squares). With that small of graphics you have to scale it or it will be too small.