# JavaFX Canvas scaling without anti-aliasing

Tags: java, javafx, drawing, antialiasing

I'm working on a painting program and I'd like to be able to scale (zoom) my JavaFX canvas without anti-aliasing.

After some research, I came across this: [JavaFX ImageView without any smoothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089304/javafx-imageview-without-any-smoothing/16092631#16092631) which explains the different workarounds.

I decided to implement workaround #4, which is to read the pixels from a snapshot of the canvas and scale it up and draw to an ImageView. However, this is not practical as performance is really bad, as demonstrated here by drawing moderately fast strokes on a very small canvas (640,480):

[image: performance]

I suppose I could implement a smoothing algorithm for the strokes, but I'm not sure how long it would take before I came to another stop because of this performance.

Will we ever get a: `canvas.setInterpolation(Interpolation.NEAREST_NEIGHBOUR)`? Is there another way to implement this with even better performance?

My last resort is to go back to Swing which actually can be set to disable interpolation.