# JavaFx Image fit to Pane bad Quality

Tags: java, image, javafx, imageview, pane

I'm trying to create a `GridPane` containing images of equal height and width. I've put each `ImageView` into a `Pane` because without the `Pane` the `ImageView` elements don't seem to scale correctly. It kinda works with the `Pane`, but the quality of the `ImageView` gets degraded.

```
public class Cell extends Pane{

public Cell(FieldCell field){
    this.field = field;

    image = new ImageView(new Image("path"));

    image.fitHeightProperty().bind(this.heightProperty());
    image.fitWidthProperty().bind(this.widthProperty());

    this.getChildren().add(image);
}
```

That's the Code.

Original Picture:

[image]

When inserted into a `Pane`:

[image]

I've also used other Pictures.

Maybe it doesn't look that bad in your opinion but if I use `ImageView` only and set the `Width` (not `fitWidth`) it looks much better.

Comment: It's difficult to know what your issue is.  A related question is: [JavaFX ImageView without any smoothing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089304/javafx-imageview-without-any-smoothing), though that answer may not assist you.

Comment: well this is upscaling not downscaeing

Comment: What is upscaling?  Rendering an image in an area larger than the image bitmap itself?  If so, how much larger? 20%, 500%?  If you do that with a bitmap, you are either going to get jaggy images (if no smoothing algorithm is applied) or blurry images (if a smoothing algorithm is applied).  Vector based image formats (such as svg) will scale up and down smoothly, but JavaFX does not directly support them, though you can get the basics to work if you search related answers on StackOverflow.

Comment: i meant your link is upscaling my Problem is downscaling