# How to disable linear filtering for drawImage on canvas in javafx

Tags: javafx

I'm trying to draw scaled image on canvas in javafx. Using this code:

```
Image image = ...;
canvas.setWidth(scale * width);
canvas.setHeight(scale * height);
GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();    
gc.drawImage(image, 0, 0, scale * width, scale * height);
// this gives same result
// gc.scale(scale, scale);
// gc.drawImage(editableImage, 0, 0, width, height);
```

It works really fast but makes blurred images like this:

[image]

This is not what I'd like to see. Instead I want to get this picture:

[image]

Which can be drawn by manually setting each pixel color with such code:

```
PixelReader reader = image.getPixelReader();
PixelWriter writer = gc.getPixelWriter();
for (int y = 0; y < scale * height; ++y) {
    for (int x = 0; x < scale * width; ++x) {
        writer.setArgb(x, y, reader.getArgb(x / scale, y / scale));
    }
}
```

But I cannot use this approach as it's too slow. It took couple of seconds to draw 1Kb image scaled 8 times. So I ask if there's any way to disable this blurry effect for drawing on canvas?

Comment: Related, maybe even a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089304/javafx-imageview-without-any-smoothing

Comment: @fabian as you can see this question is about ImageView. Canvas is quite different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPD 10/07/2019:**

Looks like the issue is [fixed](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8204060)! Now GraphicsContext should have property ["image smoothing"](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html#setImageSmoothing(boolean)) controlling this behavior.

**INITIAL ANSWER**

I guess I've found answer to my question. As [this issue](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8091877?jql=project%20%3D%20JDK%20AND%20component%20%3D%20javafx%20AND%20text%20%7E%20%22canvas%20drawimage%22%20ORDER%20BY%20updated%20DESC%2C%20priority%20DESC%2C%20created%20ASC) says that there's no way to specify filtering options in graphics context.

Description:

> When drawing an image in a GraphicsContext using the drawImage()
> method to enlarge a small image to a larger canvas, the image is being
> interpolated (possibly using a bilinear or bicubic algorithm). But
> there are times like when rendering color maps (temperature,
> zooplancton, salinity, etc.) or some geographical data (population
> concentration, etc.) where we want to have no interpolation at all
> (ie: use the nearest neighbor algorithm instead) in order to represent
> accurate data and shapes.
>
> In Java2D, this is possible by setting the appropriate
> RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING on the Graphics2D at hand. Currently on
> JavaFX's GraphicsContext there is no such way to specify how the image
> is to be interpolated.
>
> The same applies when shrinking images too.
>
> This could be expanded to support a better form of smoothing for the
> "smooth" value that is available in both Image and ImageView and that
> does not seem to work very well currently (at least on Windows).

The issue was created in 2013 but it's still untouched so unlikely it will be resolved soon.