# JavaFX isometric rendering

Tags: java, javafx, render, pixel, isometric

Could you guys please help me out with this:

I'm trying to write a simple isometric game in JavaFX, but I'm not sure how should I render it properly. I was thinking about drawing the background in photoshop and then add it to the game as ImageView. So I did:

```
ImageView image = new ImageView("file:res/img/BACKGROUND.png");
image.setScaleX(4);
image.setScaleY(4);
image.setLayoutX(150);
image.setLayoutY(150);
add(image); // root.getChilder().add(image);
```

And so the result was like that:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoYeK.jpg

Of course, I understand, if I remove scaling, it'd be like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DPyM.jpg

the quality would be totally fine, but I want it to be zoomed.
Is there any ideas how could I do that?

Should I render it in some another way, or try to make picture larger itself (if so, how?)

I'd be really grateful for any help.

Comment: You did get a scaled image. How is this differemt from the desired output???

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The second image is blurred, colors are not that good quality either. Please look at his picture from the PC

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089304/javafx-imageview-without-any-smoothing

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this problem is not related to JavaFX as it seems.
I'm going to move this question to the photoshop category.